# Storing code metrics

Tags: code-metrics, pre-commit-hook

I'd like to write a pre-commit hook that tells you if you've improved/worsened some code metric of a project (i.e. average function length). The hook would have to know what the previous average function length was and I don't know where to store that information. One option would be to store an additional *.metrics* file in the repo but that sounds clunky. Another option would be to `git stash`, compute the metrics, `git stash pop`, compute the metrics again and print the delta. I'm inclined to go with the latter. Are the any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am author of the [Metrix++](http://metrixplusplus.sourceforge.net/home.html) tool, which I am using in the workflow I described below. I guess the same workflow can be executed with other tools capable to compare the results.*

---

One of the ideas you suggested works perfectly, if you add a couple of CI checks (see the steps below). I find it solid. Not sure why you are considering it clunky.

I have got a file with metrics results which is updated before each commit and stored in VCS. Let's name this file metrics.db, and consider automation of the following workflow on build/test of a project:

1) if metrics.db has not been changed since last checkout (i.e. it is the original data for the previous/base revision), copy it to metrics-prev.db

2) Collect metrics for current code, what produces metrics.db file again. *Note: It is very helpful when a metrics tool can do iterative scans for the best performance (i.e. calculate metrics for updated functions/classes), so it gives you the opportunity to run metrics tool on every build, including iterative.*

3) Compare metrics-prev.db with metrics.db. If metrics identify regressions, fail the build and [optionally] do not allow to commit - team rule. If metrics are good, build is successful, and commit may happen.

4) [optionally] you may run Continuous Integration (CI) which validates that the actual committed metrics.db file corresponds to the committed code for the same revision (i.e. do the same 1-3 steps and make sure that the diff is zero at the step 3). If diff is not zero, it means somebody forgot to update the metrics.db file, and presumably did not execute pre-commit check, so revert the change.

5) [optionally] CI may do steps 1-3 if you fetch metrics.db as metrics-prev.db from the previous revision. In this case, CI may also check that the collected metrics.db is the same as committed (alternative or addition for the step 4).

---

Another implementation I have seen: metrics.db files are stored in a separate drive, out of VCS, and custom script is able to locate corresponding metrics.db for a revision. I find this solution unreliable as the drive can disappear, files can be moved and renamed, and so on. So, placing the file in VCS is better solution, but any will work.

---

I have attempted to do the alternative you suggested: switch to the previous revision and run the metrics tool twice. I abandoned this approach for several reasons: metrics check script alters your source files (so, it is impossible to include it into iterative rebuild and continue to work smoothly with your IDE as it will complain about changed files), and secondly it is very slow performance (comparing with iterative re-scans, it is extremely slow).

Hope it helps.